# creating hyperlinks in jlist in java

Tags: java

I have search this alot and found little guidance. Can someone guide me towards the best path to creating workable hyperlinks in a Jlist in a java swing application?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a no frills way of doing it.

```
jList1.addListSelectionListener(this);

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
   if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
      return;

   String url = (String)jList1.getSelectedValue();

   //Assume browser is supported on Desktop API
   Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
}
```

I'm using the default model here and the value displayed is the URL. Runs on JDK 1.6